# CSS "em" issue: avoid scaling to font-size of specific element

Tags: css, font-size

My site is almost totally designed in "em" (as opposed to px). It is supposed to be much better for modern browsers.

Most of the text is font-size:1em. 1em = 16px by default, I didn't specify it.

But I have some content where font-size is 1.2em and other which is 0.8em (for example for H1 or for small buttons).

The issue with "em" is that it re-scale all the sizes of an element (margin, padding, height...) according to the font-size.

I have the specific code in my CSS:

```
/* Reset */
html [and many other elements] {
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
}
/* Design */
body {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1; /* Line height will equal the em of each element */
}
.small-button {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
.normal-button {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

The normal-button has a margin of 1x1x16 = 16px. But the small-button has a margin of 1x0.8x16 = 12.8px.

Apparently this is a specific "em" property (it would not be the case in "px") which scales everything according to the font-size of the element.

This example is simple; but on my website it makes things really hard for me to keep things consistent.

How can I de-activate this property so that in the example above the 2 buttons have the same margin? (without re-calculating the sizes; which is what I am doing right now!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the purpose of the em unit that it is relative to the currently set font size. If you want to use an consistent form of em, use the unit 'rem'. It is relative to the root element of your page (most likely your html tag) and stands for root em.

Check out this article by Jonathan Snook if you want to learn more about it. 
http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Comment: Hi Haroldchen.Would you recommend using "rem" or is it too specific and a no-go area ? I can see here http://caniuse.com/rem that there is 82% compatibility against 100% for "em"...

Comment: It really depends on what your target is. IE8 and OperaMini are the real issue here. you could polyfill for those two browsers ( https://github.com/chuckcarpenter/REM-unit-polyfill ).
Or you adjust your em units every time when redfining your font-size. Personally I'm using ems for most of my projects adjust em values as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I set my "master unit" in the body and proceed in multiples of 10s. I hate 16pt as stock, because I don't want to use a chart to set my font sizes the sizes I want them.

`body { font-size:10pt; }`

As far as particular elements, keep in mind that if you have an element (say a `ul`) with a size of `1.2em`, and the `li` set to `1.0`, and your body is `10pt`, then the `li` is actually *based* off it's parent container, so it would be `1.2em` instead of `1.0`(aka `10pt` as set in the body), because it's **parent** is `1.2em`.

If you have something that you want a specific size throughout (such as a main menu), I suggest you forgo the `em` method on that particular parent object (or the `li` themselves) and use a set `px` or `pt` method.