# Changing CSS font-size alters other -em settings?

Tags: html, css, layout, fonts

I'm trying to use em-units instead of px in a design, so that it scales well across screen / device / etc.

What I'm seeing is that when defining non-font things like "margin" or "padding" in terms of em-units, then when I alter the font-size within the same element, it changes the non-font elements.  For example:

```
header {
  font-size: 1em;  # is default
  margin: 1em;     # will be 16pt
}
```

vs

```
div {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin: 1em;     # is now 40pt?
}
```

So my questions:

- Are -em units supposed to behave this way for non-font elements?  (I assume so, but just checking...)?
- And, if not -em, then what flexible unit am I supposed to use for things like element positioning?

If it helps, I created a jsfiddle to test these things out: https://jsfiddle.net/0emnypou/

EDIT: It appears this may be a near-duplicate of: [CSS "em" issue: avoid scalling to font-size of specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333067/css-em-issue-avoid-scalling-to-font-size-of-specific-element?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the first question: Yes, `em` units will (almost) always correspond to the current element's font-size, no matter the property you're using it on.

For a consistent "value", you could use `rem`s , that stands for "root em", and that value will always be the same as the `font-size` that is set on your `html`.

You could also use `vw` and `vh`, which stands for "viewport width" and "viewport height"

> em - Relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font)
>
> rem - Relative to font-size of the root element
>
> vw - Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport
>
> vh - Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport
>
> vmin - Relative to 1% of viewport's smaller dimension
>
> vmax - Relative to 1% of viewport's larger dimension

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: `1rem` is the font size as set on the `html`. Setting only the `body` font size will not change the size of the `rem`. Oh, and just to be pedantic: no, `em` units will not _always_ correspond to the current element's font size. There are properties for which they don't.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I didn't know about that last part ... In which cases does that happen?

Comment: I only meant the `font` and `font-size` property use the parent's font size rathere than the current element's font size. Sorry if that confused you.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest setting a base font size, say in  and then use the rem unit (always refers back to the base font). I went to your jsfiddle and made these changes and it seems to work (only the  changed in size).

```
`**body {font-size: 14pt;}**
header, article, footer {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: **1rem**;
}

header {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  background-color: DarkTurquoise;
}

article {
  background-color: LightCyan;
 }

footer {
  font-size: **0.5rem**;
  background-color: DarkTurquoise;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ems are dependent upon the font-size regardless of the element they are used with. 'em' is (was) tied to the width of a capital letter M.

['rem'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Rems) on the other hand is the 'root M', meaning that the size is relative to the first declaration of the font-size. rems are particularly useful for the situation you describe.